# Html: how to align words in a table

Tags: html, css

I have created a table inside a column in another table.
I want to align the two words
[image: this is the image]

```
<table width="223">
    <tr>
        <td width="215">      
            <form method="post" action="AggiornaQtaCarrelloServlet">
                <input type="text" name="quantita" pattern="[0-9]*" required value="<%=articoli.get(a).intValue()%>" size="3"/> 
                <input type="hidden" name="codice" value="<%=a.getCodice()%>"/>
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit();">Aggiorna Q.tà</a>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="RimuoviArticoloDaCarrelloServlet">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_articolo" value="<%=a.getId()%>"/>
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit();">Rimuovi</a>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thats because 2nd row has no input type="text" so it has to align to left.

Comment: In the css they are align to the center.How can i solve it?

Comment: than do `td a { display: block; }`    ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the way it's laid out just a bit: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F2vUv/3/)**

Split the input and the link into two separate `td`. Then add a blank `td` to the second row before that link. Then you'll need to change the width of the first `td`. You'll also need to move the first `form` to surround both `td` elements, so you'll have to add a `table` to the very first `td`. In order to keep the alignment, I've done the same to the second row's `td`

```
<table width="223">
<tr>
    <td width="223">
        <form method="post" action="AggiornaQtaCarrelloServlet">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50">
                        <input type="text" name="quantita" pattern="[0-9]*" required value="<%=articoli.get(a).intValue()%>" size="3" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="codice" value="<%=a.getCodice()%>" />
                    </td>
                    <td> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit();">Aggiorna Q.tà</a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="223">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="50"></td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="RimuoviArticoloDaCarrelloServlet">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_articolo" value="<%=a.getId()%>" /> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit();">Rimuovi</a>

                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the first form is not closed..Can you modify the html code?

Comment: I've fixed the code. A form can't be a child of a `tr`, so I've added a table inside the first `td` enclosed inside the `form`. I had to add the same inner html to keep the alignment.

Comment: The javascript code works but they are not align..This table is inside a column of another table..In the style.css the element of table are align to center

Comment: Refresh and take a look. I had to add the same table layout inside the second row. I'm guessing you checked before I got that in there.

Comment: Only the javascript link Rimuovi  works. But Aggiorna Q.tà does'nt works .Sorry brouxhaha

Comment: The form is no longer a direct `parentNode` of the link, so try something like this: `parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.submit()`: http://jsfiddle.net/F2vUv/4/. Although, you may want to separate the JavaScript from the HTML, and use a function, so it's not so archaic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an inline styling you need something like

> ```
>         <td width="215" style="text-align: center;">
> ```